# Softmax function defined in Tensorflow Github repository

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, github

I am going through the GitHub source code for Softmax activation function. I have a few questions regarding the code.

1. `m = x.max(1)[:, np.newaxis]` has been used to find the maximum in the array provided. What is the need for `np.newaxis` in this expression?
2. `u = np.exp(x - m)` has been used but to my knowledge, it should have been `u = np.exp(x)`. What implementational detail am I missing?
3. `z = u.sum(1)[:, np.newaxis]`. Similar to earlier this code also uses `np.newaxis`. What is its use here?

For your better understanding here is the [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e5bf8de410005de06a7ff5393fafdf832ef1d4ad/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_test.py#L100) to the github repo where this function is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function under discussion is as follows:

```py
def softmax(x):
    assert len(x.shape) == 2
    m = x.max(1)[:, np.newaxis]
    u = np.exp(x - m)
    z = u.sum(1)[:, np.newaxis]
    return u / z
```

As the `assert` statement suggets, the softmax function must be applied to a **2D array**; and so that all rows of the result `u / z` sum to one. That's why the methods `max` and `sum` are applied **row-wise**, *i.e*. with parameter `axis=1`.

#### Broadcasting and `np.newaxis`

For each row `x[i]` of `x`, we want to compute `np.exp(x[i]) / np.sum(np.exp(x[i]))`. Here the normalization term `np.sum(np.exp(x[i]))` is a number, while the term `np.exp(x[i])` is a 1D array. Thanks to numpy's [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), the operation can be performed.

Now, iterating on the rows of `x` can be avoided thanks to numpy. Let's  take as an example the following array for `np.exp(x)`.

```py
u = np.array([[ 9,  6, 13, 19,  8],
              [ 2, 17, 18,  0, 13],
              [ 8,  3,  2, 18, 10]])  # np.exp(x)
u.sum(axis=1)  # normalization term: array([55, 50, 41])
```

The aim is to divide each row of `u` by the corresponding value of the normalization term `u.sum(axis=1)`. However, broadcasting rules do not allow the two terms to be divided directly, since `u` has shape `(3, 5)`, while the normalization array has shape `(3,)`. As numpy's [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) indicates :

> Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1

So `u` can be divided by arrays of shape `(3, 5)`, `(1, 5)`, `(3, 1)`, `(5,)` or `()` but not by `u.sum(1)` of shape `(3,)`.

That's why the index operator `newaxis` is used to insert a new axis into the normalization term, making it two-dimensional with shape `(3, 1)`.

```py
u.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]  # array([[55], [50], [41]])
```

Finally a softmax function on rows would be

```py
def softmax(x):
     assert x.dim == 2
     u = np.exp(x)
     z = u.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
     return u / z
```

#### Numeric stability

However applying this function on large values can be numerically unstable, since `np.exp(x)` may be very large. Note that  subtracting of adding any constant will not change the result thanks to the normalization term.

[image: no effect when adding a constant]

That's why the maxima of each row `m` are subtracted, so that all values are below zero before applying the exponential function.